# How much should the players get paid?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I can't seem to find a good guide to what the range is on how much nuyen the players should get paid per run.  Is it in a book somewhere, or does someone have some experience in this regard?

Comment: They should get paid with a betrayal from Mr. Johnson :-)

Comment: Removed my answer as it covers all the points made in the dublicate @SevenSidedDie made

Comment: @Daily Consider submitting it on the other question though! Yours is short but detailed, and that has value. I think it would compete with / complement the existing answers there well.

Comment: Thanks @SevenSidedDie I have however added a bit more text/clarification on that as the other thread OP was looking for figures :)